# Good Rails forum plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, forum

I am creating a rails app that needs to have a social-forum like behavior. Can anyone suggest a good plugin for rails that will let me build on top of it, without having to re-invent the wheel?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some looking through google results

https://github.com/tog/tog/wiki/developer-faq
http://communityengine.org/documentation.html

Hope it help others.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is still maintained but looks like there is a lot of forks if its not:

http://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast

Answer (score 1):

here is the whole list, can be helpful: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/forum_systems

Answer (score 0):

[Thredded](https://thredded.org/) is a great forum engine and was built for extensibility.

Because Thredded is a Rails engine, it is very easy to integrate it into an existing app.

[image: Thredded demo screenshot]